# Display an animate two shapes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cashapelayer, animatewithduration

I have a `CircleView : UIView` class that animates (shrinks and grows) when you touch it (via the `pop` function).  I would also like for a stroked circle to appear and grow out (like a basic water ripple) when you touch it too. (The effect I am talking about is shown [here in CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/))

How do I go about doing this?

Some more information:

- Ideally both animations would be controllable from the single `CircleView` class
- `CircleView` inherits off `UIView`

**Update**

Based on answers I have added a new object to via a `subLayer`.  This displays ok BUT it doesn't animate during the `pop`. Can anyone help me understand why?

Here is my current code (the pertinent bits anyway)

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self setLayerProperties];
}

- (void)setLayerProperties {
//The view’s Core Animation layer used for rendering.
CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;

UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
                                                  byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners
                                                        cornerRadii:self.frame.size];
layer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
layer.fillColor = _Color.CGColor;

rippleLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
layer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
layer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
[layer addSublayer:rippleLayer];
}

// Does the animated "pop"
- (void)pop{

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [self animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    [animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8f]];
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
    [animation setDuration:0.15];
    [animation setAutoreverses:YES];

    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];

    rippleLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
    CABasicAnimation *scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    [scale setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
    [scale setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f]];
    [scale setRepeatCount:1];
    [scale setDuration:1.0f];
    //r[scale setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
    [scale setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

    [rippleLayer addAnimation:scale forKey:scale.keyPath];
}
```

Comment: You can do many things inside of the animations block, you are not constrained to just adjusting one single property. If the second effect you desire fits inside of the time constraints, just make multiple statements there. Otherwise try calling multiple animations in succession, the method doesn't wait for each completion block, it will fire them all off in sequence, with millisecond delays between. For many effects, that delay is completely indistinguishable from simultaneous.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I know I can do multipole things within the animation block, I suppose the real question is how do I add another "object" to animate?

Comment: commonly the view that you call the animation on will be the parent of many subviews that you are animating. Your example is animating itself, but you can animate any property of any object you have a reference to (assuming it's an animatable property...)

Comment: ie. self.someProperty.somePropertyWhichIsAView.frame = etc...  that sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

Just add the other objects you want to animate to your layer and set their alpha to 0.0. You can then play with that value in or immediately before your animation.

I noticed that you did not follow the convention of naming variables with small initial. `_color` would be preferable to `_Color`.

Also, if you want to put the layer into its original state you usually use the identify transform matrix:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Comment: I keep having bad naming practices atm, Ill try remember to be better.  How can I add another element to the layer and keep a reference to it?   I would also then have to animate the "pop" different wouldnt I as I would have to animate the `bezierPath` rather than the entire `UIView`?

Comment: You can add views (`addSubview:`) or layers (`addSublayer:`). Keep a reference by declaring a private variable (above at `@implementation`, between `{}`).

Comment: I have done that but the second layer doesnt animate, please see my update, thanks :)